# Knockoutjs: bind value to span, save from different textbox

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am faced with the following issue: Im binding JSON data with Knockout.js to multiple spans:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function viewModel() {
        self.inlogGegevens = ko.observable();

        function inlogGegevensViewModel(data) {
            this.UserId = data.UserId;
            // more bindings...
            return this;
        }

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            self.inlogGegevens(inlogGegevensViewModel(data));
            ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

This works as expected. The spans are showing the JSON correctly. But... the client requests that the user should edit the value **in a new, javascript-generated textbox**. The value in this newly generated textbox needs to be sent back to the viewmodel and posted to the server when the user hits the 'Save' button.

Below is a snippet of the JavaScript function that gets called when the user clicks the 'Change' button (not my code):

```
function editable() {
    var editable_td = $(this).find(".editable");
    var editable_element = $(this).find(".editable .value");
    var OriginalContent = editable_element.html();
    $(this).unbind('click', editable).addClass("editing");
    editable_element.siblings(".action").hide();
    editable_element.html("<input class='w100p form-control' type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
    editable_element.children().first().focus();
    editable_element.data("original", OriginalContent);
};
```

I'm not looking for a working solution (I can't post the complete code), but rather a hint in the right direction on how to implement that.

What would be the best solution in a scenario where you bind a value to one HTML tag (the span) and save the value of another tag (the JS-generated textbox) back to the client?

Comment: Show your markup please

Comment: Javascript generated textbox? When does it get generated? What triggers it? That should be part of your view model.

Comment: The code is missing some brackets, so it can't really work. Please correct that and post a link to a JSFiddle including your code.

Comment: @SteenT: ive added some javascript code that generates the textbox.

Comment: Well, you should stick with knockout and bindings, to make it easier. Mixing in jquery (or whatever other framework), will just make it harder to make a clean solution. If you have a "change" button, I would have that call a method on your view model, set a boolean to show the inputbox (and a save button), when save is clicked, push the change to the server.